# Proving Convexity of an Open Disk

Tags: convex-analysis

I need to prove that the following set is convex:

$$ \{(x,y):x^2 +y^2 \lt 2\} $$

Obviously, this an open disk of radius $\sqrt2$.

My intuition is to use triangle inequality for this proof because a similar example was done in class. However, I've never used triangle inequality or proved that a set is convex, so if someone could help me out with that, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251414/proof-that-this-set-is-convex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to show that if $a\in S=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<2\}$ and $b\in S$ then $\lambda a + (1-\lambda b)\in S$ for any $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$.  Use what you know about being in $a$ and $b$ being in $S$ to show that $\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$ is in $S$.

The triangle inequality is that $\Vert a + b\Vert\leq \Vert a\Vert + \Vert b\Vert$.  What you know is that $\Vert a\Vert < 2$ and $\Vert b\Vert < 2$.  Apply the triangle inequality to $\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$.

Comment: Is $\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$

Comment: Sorry for the typo... I corrected it.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your set is equal to any element with norm less than $\sqrt{2}$, then take $a$ and $b$ with that property:

$$||\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b||\leq \lambda||a||+(1-\lambda)||b||< \lambda \sqrt{2}+(1-\lambda) \sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}  $$

Comment: Well, there it is. Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean the set contains any element whose 2-norm (or euclidean norm) is smaller than sqrt(2).  The 2-norm squared is also a norm, in that case it is the set of numbers where that norm is smaller than 2.