# Proof that $M$ is a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

I need a help with proving that M is a convex set:

$$M = \{x = (x_1, x_2)^T \mid xa^T ≥ b, x_1 \geqslant 0\}$$

I know the definition of convexity.

I tried to apply this to this set but I don't know how to prove so that it works... Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: $xa^T$ is a matrix.  What exactly do you mean in this context by $M \geq b$ if $M$ is a matrix and $b$ is a scalar?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251414/proof-that-this-set-is-convex?rq=1).

Comment: Also, please format your mathematical expressions correctly.  There's a tutorial on how the formatting works [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360)